# Wrong pub.dev score after publish

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, pub.dev

I published a package (flutter pub publish command) on pub.dev https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_persistence but when I run pana locally I get 130/130 while pub.dev score is 40.

**Pub.dev:**

[image]

What I miss here?